# How to pass "-J" options to javac through Maven?

Tags: java, maven, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a Java project which is built using Maven. I would like to add options to the "javac" command line - particularly, I want to pass a few "-J" options.

So normally I would do something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>-J-Xdebug</compilerArgument>
        <compilerArgument>-J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However when I try this I get errors of the form:

```
[ERROR] Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid flag: -J-Xdebug
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

On closer investigation, it seems that maven-compiler-plugin writes all the compiler arguments out to an options file, and invokes javac like 'javac @optionfile'. According to the official documentation for javac at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html:

> @argfiles
>       One or more files that lists options and source files. The -J options are not allowed in these files.

So it looks like the  option in maven-compiler-plugin is not going to work - it wants to use arg files, arg files cannot contain the options I want.

I've also seen some suggestions to use the  map instead - however this had similar results when I tried it.

Are there any other options?

Comment: looks like you've hit a known issue - http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-129

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler plugin allows you to [specify the location of the jdk](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html), so you could use something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <executable><!-- path-to-javac-invoking-script --></executable>
      <compilerVersion>1.3</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

and provide it with a path to a script/bat file that would pass all the arguments along to the real javac along with your extra arguments?

**EDIT** - [the original issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-129) has been fixed in compiler plugin 2.4+ and this should just work now without my workaround

Comment: Well I can confirm that it works... it's definitely a workaround however, but short of getting bugs fixed upstream and waiting for a new version of the plugins, this will work :)

Comment: @RichardDowner - you didnt ask for pretty ;-)